# Incorrect NumInGroup count for repeating group (Field=268)

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

When I recieve a Market Data Snapshot Full Refresh message, my app cannot consume it.
This is how the message looks like:

```
8=FIX.4.4|9=160|35=W|34=1625|49=DummyBroker|56=DummyID|52=20220201-15:17:17.201806|262=43_MarketDataChange|55=USD/CHF|268=6|269=0|270=0.92282|271=400000|269=1|270=0.92293|271=400000|10=227|
```

Human readable format (please ignore the Invalid lines):

[image]

Error message my app is sending back to the server: Rejected: Incorrect NumInGroup count for repeating group (Field=268)

268=6 seems ok to me, so I am guessing that something is wrong with the DataDictionary.
This is how the message appears in my DataDictionary:

```
<message name="MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh" msgtype="W" msgcat="app">
    <field name="MDReqID" required="N"/>
    <field name="Symbol" required="Y"/>
    <group name="NoMDEntries" required="Y">
        <field name="MDEntryType" required="Y"/>
        <field name="MDEntryPx" required="Y"/>
        <field name="MDEntrySize" required="Y"/>
    </group>
</message>
```

Relevant fields:

```
<field number="268" name="NoMDEntries" type="NUMINGROUP"/>
<field number="269" name="MDEntryType" type="CHAR">
  <value enum="0" description="BID" />
  <value enum="1" description="OFFER" />
</field>
<field number="270" name="MDEntryPx" type="PRICE"/>
<field number="271" name="MDEntrySize" type="QTY"/>
```

In my config file ValidateFieldsHaveValues=N, ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N.

Anyone knows where the issue is?

Comment: "268=6 seems ok to me"... Why? In only see two repeating group members (delimited by tag 269) and not six.

Comment: You are right @ChristophJohn.  NoMDEntries should represent the number of groups, not the number of data it contains, so the error must be on the broker side.

Answer (score 2):

As @ChristophJohn mentioned NoMDEntries should be 2 not 6, so the error is on the broker side.

It was already explained here:
[what is "NoMDEntries"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970005/what-is-nomdentries)

The correct message should look like this:

```
8=FIX.4.4|9=160|35=W|34=1625|49=DummyBroker|56=DummyID|52=20220201-15:17:17.201806|262=43_MarketDataChange|55=USD/CHF|268=2|269=0|270=0.92282|271=400000|269=1|270=0.92293|271=400000|10=227|
```